# some programs can access the network but not others

Tags: networking

After installing the latest updates from 22.04 LTS I ran into an issue where some programs can access the network but others seem blocked. Chrome can get on to the net but Firefox comes back with Server Not found errors. My Plex Server works just fine but Any Desk shows that it can not connect to the server. I have uninstalled both programs and reinstalled them but the same thing happens. From the terminal I can Ping Google.com but not the routers IP. The PC is connected to the router via cable and in Network Manager it shows connected. No other machine (Windows, Android and Apple) on the network are having issues.

Comment: Look at `ip route show`, `ip address show` (or, if you're lazy like me: `ip r;ip a`). Also `cat /etc/resolv.conf`. Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Do not use Add Comment.